# How To Open a Media File From a Zip File "Directly" (Without Extracting it)?

Tags: c#, media-player, dotnetzip

In C#, I'm using both the **DotNetZip** and the **System.Windows.Media**
I have a zip file that contains some songs, and I want to play them directly from the zip file without having to extract them ..

Now I manged to get a stream to the sound file:

```
Stream stream = zip["Songs\\IronMaiden\\Song1.mp3"].OpenReader();
```

but the problem is, that the **MediaPlayer.Open** method only takes **Uri** as a parameter
it doesn't take a stream ..

How Can I get around this ?
Knowing that I can't switch to any other media options like fmod.dll nor anything else.
I'll also said it again, I don't want to extract them.

Any help would be appreciated .. Thanks in advance .. :)

Comment: Why is it such a problem to extract a file to the %TEMP% directory to play it?

Comment: Some of the sound files are big, I don't want any delays.

Answer (score 1):

If the media player you want to use does not take a stream, there is no way to do it.  As has been mentioned, you'll have to save the file and use a URL to the saved file location.  Otherwise, find another media player that works with a stream.